# MSSQL Update Query Displaying Results To Grid

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an SQL Query that updates IDs in one table based on a join to records in another table. The issue is that for some reason that I do not understand the Update query is actually displaying the results on the query to the grid in SSMS. This is causing an 'Out of Memory Exception' on my machine because it is trying to show 1 million + results in the grid. It is interesting because the query should not display anything except the number of records updated. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Here is an example of my query:

```
UPDATE MyDatabase.dbo.Notes
   SET ParentID = A.ID
  FROM MyDatabase.dbo.Notes N
  JOIN MyDatabase.dbo.Actions A ON N.OldID = A.OldID
 WHERE A.OldID IS NOT NULL
   AND N.OldID IS NOT NULL
   AND N.ParentID IS NULL
```

Comment: Are there any update trigger on the updated table ? But I'm not actually sure that you could "output" a SELECT resultset in a trigger. Just guessing.

Comment: That was it. Apparently there is an update trigger with a select statement in it. I disabled the trigger and the query ran instantly. Can't believe I didn't think of that.Thanks for the help!

Comment: Might as well add an answer and mark it as the answer @Matt, that way the community will know this question has been solved! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The code listed in your question will not cause any output to the Grid in SSMS by itself**

- Double check that what you pasted is actually your exact query

  - Sometimes extra code can be hiding below the fold
- Check for triggers on any tables involved

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is an update trigger with a select statement in it. I disabled the trigger and the query ran instantly.